# How do I call a method that returns an array of words (given an input sequence)?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, string, methods

I was asked to create a method in which I input a String sequence and make an array that stores the String's words in it. So far, this is what I have:

```
public class Tester{
    public static String[] split(String s) {
        // determine the number of words
        java.util.Scanner t = new java.util.Scanner(s);
        int countWords = 0;
        String w;
        while (t.hasNext()) {
            w = t.next();
            countWords++;
        }
    // create appropriate array and store the string’s words in it
        // code here
        String[] words = new String[4]; // Since you are using an array you have to declare
        // a fixed length.
        // To avoid this, you can use an ArrayList 
        // (dynamic array) instead.
        while (t.hasNext()) {
            w = t.next();
            words[countWords] = w;
            countWords++;
        }
        return words;
    }

}
```

Now I have to call method *split* with the string *one two three four* as argument. I apologize if I sound naive. I'm new to programming. I've been watching tons of tutorials on this but when I try to call the method, my code keeps getting red markers.

*The first 14 lines of the code (from 'public class' to 'code here') are a part of the question that was given to me so they shouldn't be altered. You can change the rest of the code if necessary.

EDIT:

How do I create a main method that calls the split method? This is what I tried:

```
class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Tester object = new Tester();

        object.split(s);

        System.out.println(words[i]);

    }
}
```

Basically, I created another class that calls the split method. However, I keep getting red markers.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Please read up on the [importance of indentation](http://mrbool.com/importance-of-code-indentation/29079)

Answer (score 0):

After the first `while (t.hasNext ())` loop, your `t` scanner has been exhausted.

You need to recreate it so it starts from the begining again:

```
String[] words = new String[countWords];  // the size is countWords
t = new java.util.Scanner (s);            // recreate the scanner
int index = 0;
while (t.hasNext()) {
    words[index++] = t.next();
}
return words;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, there is a note. Since you're using an Array of Strings, `String[] words`, you need to deterministically know the length of the Array, so you can properly initialize it, fill it up and use it.

Your first looping through the Scanner, `t`, learns how many Strings your assignment gives you.

```
int countWords = 0;
while (t.hasNext()) {
    w = t.next();
    countWords++;
}
```

That means that you need at LEAST one more step to fill it up. Now that you know the `countWords`, the amount of words you are given, you can initialize your array.

`String[] words = new String[countWords]`

You've got an Array of `countWords`-in-number empty `String` objects. Time to fill them up.

**We will now go through a second loop,** and fill our `words` String Array

```
int i = 0;
while (t.hasNext()) {
    words[i] = t.next();
    i++;
}
```

That's it. Now return it to the caller.

`return words`

### A final note:

Please, read up on how to indent properly, as I said in my comment on your first post. You really can't write/read code if it isn't properly indented.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you do not need to count the number of words at all. Instead this can be done simply as

```
ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>(); This list will contain all your words
t = new java.util.Scanner (s);// scanner
while (t.hasNext()) {
    wordsList.add(t.next());
}
return wordsList.toArray();
```

The advantage of using this is that you don't need to initialize any size for either array or list.